# borei menei b’samim and perfume

Tags: smell

1. I heard that few people bother to make *borei menei b’samim* when they open a perfume or cologne or an aftershave lotion bottle. Is there a halachic source for this?
2. I heard that the *beracha* is not made when you smell the scent being worn by another person. In fact, a man may not smell perfume being worn by a woman as it is ערוה! Is there a halachic source for this?

Comment: These, IMO, are really two separate questions. You may want to [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/43632/edit) the second question _out_ of this one, and [ask a new one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for that idea.

Comment: Three, IMO, @Shokhet.

Comment: You're probably right, @msh210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to number 1 is in orach chaim siman 216 siff 6. Not pashut.
Answer to number 2 is in siman 217 siff 4.

Comment: Did you mean not פשוט?

Comment: Is not פשוט, going on the answer to number 1 or 2?

Comment: Going to number one. And yes I meant not פשוט. I wasn't aware there is a different transliterary option toget confused with.